# Pull value from related object

Tags: custom-object, related-list

I would like to be able to access a checkbox value from a related object, within my opportunity field.

Custom Object: *Shift*
Formula checkbox: *Pushed to Google Calendar*

When an opportunity is in proposal stage, we create 1 related shift to that opportunity.
Now I want to create a opportunity-report that shows 95% opportunity data, but I want to include the *Pushed to Google Calendars* checkbox.

On a report level I can not (as far as I know) pull a related object field. So now I'm looking to have an opportunity field that copies this related object value of this checkbox, so that I can add it to my report.

How do I go about doing this? I don't have experience in any Salesforce coding, but I do know my way around formula's and some basic idea of flows.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do I understand correctly and you have a look-up relationship from Shift to Opportunity? Or even a master-detail relationship,  with Shift being the detail?

Comment: @wouter van den Bijgaart, what is the relationship between opportunity & shift object? which one is child and parent?

Comment: @FelixvanHove I'm unsure whether I do to be honest. All I know is that I created my first custom Object called "Shifts" and I got it to work. My team can now click the 'create shift' actionbutton on the Opportunity object (just like 'log a call').    On the Opportunity object, I see a Related List with a couple fields.   One of these fields = "Google Calendar Shift Created" checkbox. That exact value I'd like to show in Opportunity reports! :)